# FAILED TO INITIALIZE RUN FROM PACKAGE.txt in Azure Functions - Kudu - deployed from Visual Studio

Tags: azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

When I deployed the Azure Function (.NET 6) from Visual Studio 2022 Community Version to the Azure Portal Function App, it shown me this error in the Kudu Site:

[image]

I published in this way: `Visual Studio > Project > Build > Publish > Azure Function App (Windows) - Marked the Check Box Option of "Run from Package"`

Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue.
Also, what to do for getting rid of the warning shown in yellow background?