# Access denied when connecting to Azure App Service using FTP Credentials in WinSCP

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service, winscp

**I have created .NET 6 App Service in Azure and trying to connect FTPS endpoint using WinSCP**:

[image]

**Getting access denied error**:

[image]

**Could anyone please help..!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to resolve your error, Make sure you enable **`SCM Basic Auth Publishing`** and **`FTP Basic Auth Publishing`** to **ON**

[image]

**Download the publish profile:-**

[image]

Copy the **publishurl in the** **Host name and Username, Password** from the downloaded publish profile:-

[image]

***The connection via Win-scp tool is successful with the Azure Web app .Net 6.0 via FTPS***

[image]

Comment: Could you please help me on these issues also: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78052884/the-portal-is-having-issues-getting-an-authentication-token-the-experience-rend || 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77826824/failed-to-initialize-run-from-package-txt-in-azure-functions-kudu-deployed-f ||